# Hiding a DIV by click on another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 'div' tag( by id=go) and write a script which i click on div, then  another div (by id=example) will be shown, and show some data:
this is my div :

```
  <div id="go" style="position: relative">Click</div>
  <div id="example" style="position: relative"></div>
```

and the script:

```
 $("#go").click(function () {

                   $("#example").fadeIn(1200);
                   $("#count").text('');
                    setInterval(
                         function () {
                            p(); count();
                          }, 8000);
                    });
```

and i want when i click on div(by id= go) agin the div (with id=example) be hide , How can i improve my script to do it?

Comment: why are you adding setInterval? do you want this hiding and showing to timed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) to toggle between `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` here:

```
$("#example").fadeToggle(1200);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v64c9/)**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `.toggle()`?
Reference is at [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). AFAIK it does all you need - including animation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toggle()`. Check this

```
$("#example").hide();
$("#go").click(function () {
      $("#example").toggle('slow');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rameshcharykotha/J7VcJ/)